# How to check if the §routeParams has a given param

Tags: angularjs

I want to use the same controller for creating and updating an entity, given that both things are extremely similar.

However, I don't seem to be able to check if the `$routeParams` have a given value (if the controller is used in the create route, then it will lack this parameter. I tried using a simple check such as

```
if($routeParams.theParam)
```

but this yields an exception. Of course I could catch it (which I think will be my workaround for the moment), but I wonder if there's a better way.

Comment: $routeParams.theParam should return undefined if the parameter is not present in url. The issue could be that $routeParams is null\undefined. Did you inject the $routeParams dependency in controller.

Comment: Yes, it is the same controller. The exception trace explicitly complains about the parameter not being there, when silencing it via a try-catch block, things work just fine